# Cookie Warning Alert in a website

Tags: jquery, web, joomla

Is it possible to implement a cookie warning alert in a website using jQuery?

The website is developed using joomla. So is it possible to implement jQuery module of cookie alert in Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this help? Apparently it displays an overlay at the top of the page.

https://code.google.com/p/cookie-warning-joomla/